# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99 Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My current chrome version : **98.0.4758.102**

My current selenium version: **4.1.1** and cannot download **chrome 99**. My **chrome 98** is updated to the last version, how do I get **chrome 99** assuming it's a beta version?

Trace log :

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51 (d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}) on port 59895
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "Thread-4" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'L-QLT-005', ip: '10.1.1.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--start-maximized, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --disable-popup-blocking, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--start-maximized, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --disable-popup-blocking, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors], extensions: []}}}]
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:230)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:151)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chromium_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:80)
    at io.beyn.spell/io.beyn.spell.Library.startBrowserChecker(Library.java:58)
    at io.beyn.spell/io.beyn.spell.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$Event$5(FXMLDocumentController.java:188)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51`

> `Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102`

Your chrome driver is for chrome version, which is not out yet. You have several solutions:

- You can download actual ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.102 from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and use it.
- You can download **Chrome Beta** (currently 99.0.4844.51) or **Chrome Dev** (currently 100.0.4896.12), where you have access to newer versions.
- If you are using **WebDriverManager** from `io.github.bonigarcia`, you have to set correctly browserVersion and driverVersion:

  ```
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion("98.0.4758.102").setup();
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("98.0.4758.102").setup();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51 (d537ec02474b5afe23684e7963d538896c63ac77-refs/branch-heads/4844@{#875}) on port 59895
.
Exception in thread "Thread-4" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=98.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v98.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=98.0.4758.48/) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 98

- But you are using *chromedriver=99.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=99.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 99

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=91.0* and the *chrome=96.0.4664.45*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v99.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=99* (as per [chromedriver=99.0.4844.51 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/notes.txt)).

[image: Chrome v99]