# ChromeDriver updated before Chrome did

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

So I have the exact same issue with the question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323442/this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-99-current-browser-ver/71324365#71324365)

In that question the issue is that the ChromeDriver is version 99, but Chrome is version 98. The accepted answer states that the Chrome Driver is for a version of Chrome that is "not out yet".  I am currently using this code to get the latest release of ChromeDriver

```
# get the latest chrome driver version number
chrome_url = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE'
response = requests.get(chrome_url)
version_number = response.text

# build the donwload url
download_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + version_number + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"
```

is there a way to replace the first section in the code with something that will return the current version of chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get it to work, may not be the best way but it works.

```
def get_version_via_com(filename):
    parser = Dispatch("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    try:
        v = parser.GetFileVersion(filename)
    except Exception:
        return None
    return v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get Version of Chrome
    paths = [r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
             r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"]
    version = list(filter(None, [get_version_via_com(p) for p in paths]))[0]

    # build the donwload url
    download_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + version + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"

    # download the zip file using the url built above
    latest_driver_zip = wget.download(download_url, 'chromedriver.zip')

    # extract the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(latest_driver_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall()  # you can specify the destination folder path here
    # delete the zip file downloaded above
    os.remove(latest_driver_zip)
```