# After chrome update, Message: target frame detached

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)
```

which is often displayed after running my program, since the update of chrome. I suppose it's due to the fact that the version of chrome and chromedriver don't match exactly. Indeed I have the version 102.0.5005.63 of chrome (up to date) and I have the version 102.0.5005.61 of chromedriver (its last version is 103.0.5060.24 but it's obviously not compatible with my chrome version and the version 102.0.5005.63 of chromedriver does not exist).

How can I solve the problem? I saw that one of the solutions was to re-download an older version of chrome but if possible I would like to keep an updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced same issue, please check the accepted answer here :
[This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99 Current browser version is 98.0.4758.102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323442/this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-99-current-browser-ver)

in few words you can download Chrome dev version or beta version to match both versions of `chromeDriver` and `Chrome`